# Site configured on IIS 8 classic mode - unable to read configuration file

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

A web site of ours, designed using WCSF design pattern, using MS Practices library, worked fine while configured in IIS 6. We migrated the app to new server with IIS 8. Site didn't work in the Integrated Mode as it was unable to fetch the logged on user Context. Hence we changed to "Classic mode" and the site started to work.

Now we get the following error in the site

"'Cannot read configuration file 'trying to read configuration data from file '\?\', line number '0'.  The data field contains the error code"

We have to restart the server if we receive the error.

I want to know if this is the problem in using the "Classic mode" in IIS 8 or any other problem. IIS event viewer doesn't give more than the error mentioned above.

Please help if any other configuration needs to be done or am I missing something here.